# Http Client application to test REST API with oauth

Tags: api, testing, rest, oauth

I am currently developing an application that will have a regular web interface but also a RESTful API that will be used mostly on mobile phone apps. I am using the Rails [OAuth-plugin](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin) here, so my API supports OAuth 1 and 2. This works all fine so far.

The only problem I have is with testing the API. I have found some tools that I can use to make requests to my API like [RESTConsole for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) or [RESTed](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/rested/id421879749?mt=12) and they all can test OAuth, but they don't provide an API themselves that I can use as the **callback service**. When I register an OAuth client in my application I have to enter some fake callback URL, do the authorization process and then get the *OAuth token* from the database and insert it into the console manually. Especially when testing the revocation of tokens this gets pretty cumberome.

Does anybody know of any test clients that can totally automate the testing process? That means that the test cleint includes some sort of callable endpoint that I can use as the callback URL for my app...

Thanks for your help in advance. I've been searching the internet for quite some time now and this is my last resort before starting to develop my own.

---

I will be going to accept Jon's answer, although I am not very pleased with the solution ... Whoever is interested, I'm going to roll my own little test client. If anybody is interested: https://github.com/klaustopher/knole

Comment: To those who voted to close.  The OP has stated the specific problem with the tools they have tried and is looking for a tool that can resolve that problem.  This is not a "which tool is best" kind of question.  It is one where there is a factual answer: yes this tool can do it.

Comment: A combination of Ghost Inspector and Runscope can be used to complete the OAuth 2 web flow testing. Here is a blog posts on a subject blog.runscope.com/posts/

Comment: Did you make any progress on your own test-client? The github link is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apigee](http://apigee.com/about/products/free) offers a free API Console that supports a large number of authorization schemes, including OAuth 1. Not sure if it supports 2-legged OAuth, but you can **definitely define a callback** within their service.

Comment: So far so good, thanks for the link, didn't know about that service. They support OAuth 1, 2 and 2-legged (which I just realized I am not using). But to test anything on my API I have to give a "full" description of my API in `WADL` format. That seems like a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Last time I tried to the service I simply uploaded a really simple WADL to get on with it. Once the Console was up I could still formulate my own API requests without them having been defined in the WADL.